# ReactJS: Fire Method when Component is rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I got a general question about ReactJS:

Is it possible to fire a method as soon as all the JSX-Components (`<div> components </div>`) are successfully rendered? So if some are only rendered on certain conditions could i fire a method as soon as all of them are `true`.

How would i check if everything got sucessfully rendered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lifecycle method `componentDidMount` that will get called immediately after react renders the component, it will get called once, only after the initial rendering, i think you can use that method.

As per [DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount):

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you
>   need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to
>   instantiate the network request. Setting state in this method will
>   trigger a re-rendering.

**About second ques:**

You are rendering the elements on the basis of some conditions, i am assuming that you are using some kind of bool or checking the length of array, so there is a lifecycle method [componentWillUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate), it will get called before the react re-render the component (it will not get called on initial rendering) inside this method you can check for all conditions and call any method if all the conditions are true.
So whenever you do `setState` it will get called and you can put the logic here.

Comment: That was exactly what i needed! I was fetching some data from a rest endpoint and needed a timer to stop whenever the data is displayed at the browser. Worked with the componentWillUpdate lifecycle method. Thanks a lot

Comment: glad, it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a skeleton, but it should help you to get to the solution that you're looking for:

```
type ChildProps = {
    onUpdated: () => void;
}

class MyChildComponent extends React.component<ChildProps, void> {
    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.props.onUpdated();
    }

    render() {
        ...
    }
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component<void, void> {
    private childCount: number;
    private updated: number;

    constructor() {
        this.childCount = 2;
    }

    render() {
        this.updated = 0;

        return (
            <div>
                <MyChildComponent onUpdated={ this.childUpdated.bind(this) } />
                <MyChildComponent onUpdated={ this.childUpdated.bind(this) } />
            </div>
        );
    }

    private childUpdated() {
        this.updated++;
        if (this.updated === this.childCount) {
            // do something...
        }
    }
}
```